# Convert array with subarrays to stdClass

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I have an array with sub-array:

```
$test = array("hello" => "world", "object" => array("bye" => "world"));
```

I want to convert it to object:

```
$obj = (object) $test;
```

The parent array becomes object, but child is still array:

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'hello' => string 'world' (length=5)
  public 'object' => 
    array (size=1)
      'bye' => string 'world' (length=5)
```

But I want to get something like this:

```
object(stdClass)[1]
  public 'hello' => string 'world' (length=5)
  public 'object' => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'bye' => string 'world' (length=5)
```

This could be reached with this code:

```
$testObj = json_decode(json_encode($test));
```

But it's bad practice. How can I reach this result?

Answer (score 3):

Try This may help.

[how to convert multidimensional array to object in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169892/how-to-convert-multidimensional-array-to-object-in-php)

```
function convert_array_to_obj_recursive($a) {
if (is_array($a) ) {
    foreach($a as $k => $v) {
        if (is_integer($k)) {
            // only need this if you want to keep the array indexes separate
            // from the object notation: eg. $o->{1}
            $a['index'][$k] = convert_array_to_obj_recursive($v);
        }
        else {
            $a[$k] = convert_array_to_obj_recursive($v);
        }
    }

    return (object) $a;
}

// else maintain the type of $a
return $a; 
}
```

Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function cast($array) {
    if (!is_array($array)) return $array;
    foreach ($array as &$v) {
        $v = cast($v);
    }
    return (object) $array;
}
$result = cast($test);
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/ZCNxB3)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using this way, via a foreach and conditions:

```
$array = array("hello" => "world", "object" => array("bye" => "world"));

foreach($array as $key => $val) {

    if(is_array($val)) {
        $aa[$key] = (object) $val; 
    }
    else {
        $aa[$key] = $val;
    }

    $obj  = (object) $aa;
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($obj);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
$object = new stdClass();
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    $object->$key = $value;
}
```

and use in built in json `$object = json_decode(json_encode($array), FALSE);`..It converts all your sub arrays into objects..

If this is not the answer you are expecting please comment below

Answer (score 0):

```
function arrayToObject($arr) {
    if (is_array($arr)) 
        return (object) array_map(__FUNCTION__, $arr);

    else
        return $arr;
}
```

The output of `arrayToObject($test)` would then be,

```
stdClass Object
(
    [hello] => world
    [object] => stdClass Object
        (
            [bye] => world
        )

)
```