# convert json array to json object in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

I am getting data from database using join query in `laravel` & pass to `json` and getting some result in array but I want object that I given below

Controller code:

```
$resultPastActivity= DB::table('table_user_create_activity')
                            ->join('table_sub_category','table_user_create_activity.selected_activity_id', '=', 'table_sub_category.sub_category_id')
                            ->select('sub_category_name','area','activity_type','activity_date','start_time','end_time')
                            ->whereDate('activity_date', '<', $todayDate)
                            ->where('user_id',$user_id)
                            ->get();

 return response()->json(['success' => '1','data' =>$resultPastActivity]);
```

The above code will give following json that is in array actually i want json in object

```
{
    "success": "1",
    "data": [
        {
            "sub_category_name": "Badminton",
            "area": "Rankala lake",
            "activity_type": "1",
            "activity_date": "2018-01-12",
            "start_time": "15:04:49",
            "end_time": "20:05:69"
        },
        {
            "sub_category_name": "Football",
            "area": "Devakar panad",
            "activity_type": "1",
            "activity_date": "2018-01-15",
            "start_time": "15:04:49",
            "end_time": "20:05:69"
        },
    ]
}



i want json as follows
{
    "success": "1",
    "data": {
        {
            "sub_category_name": "Badminton",
            "area": "Rankala lake",
            "activity_type": "1",
            "activity_date": "2018-01-12",
            "start_time": "15:04:49",
            "end_time": "20:05:69"
        },
        {
            "sub_category_name": "Football",
            "area": "Devakar panad",
            "activity_type": "1",
            "activity_date": "2018-01-15",
            "start_time": "15:04:49",
            "end_time": "20:05:69"
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: You tried flatten()? Thats an method for Collections.

Comment: quick way to do this `$obj = json_decode(json_encode($array));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert multidimensional array to object in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169892/how-to-convert-multidimensional-array-to-object-in-php)

Comment: i tried but get same json with array? suggest another method

Comment: That is not valid json, to have multiple objects in a structure you need to wrap it in an array, you want an object of multiple objects which is not possible

Answer (score 0):

try this, json_encode($json, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)  [JSON_FORCE_OBJECT](https://www.php.net/json_encode)

```
$result=array();
$result["0"]=$resultPastActivity;
$json=json_encode((object)$result,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
return response()->json(['success' => '1','data' =>$json]);
```

Comment: i tried but can not get expected result plz need another solutions

Comment: yes This is result contain "\0" that is not expected {
    "success": "1",
    "data": "{\"0\":{\"0\":{\"sub_category_name\":\"Badminton\",\"area\":\"Rankala lake\",\"activity_type\":\"1\",\"activity_date\":\"2018-01-12\",\"start_time\":\"15:04:49\",\"end_time\":\"20:05:69\"},\"1\":{\"sub_category_name\":\"Football\",\"area\":\"Devakar panad\",\"activity_type\":\"1\",\"activity_date\":\"2018-01-15\",\"start_time\":\"15:04:49\",\"end_time\":\"20:05:69\"},}}}"

Comment: Please show the updated answer add  $json=json_encode((object)$result,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);  type cast $result with (object) @smitapatil

Answer (score 0):

The one you want is *not* a valid JSON, you can check it here: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

So, you cannot create such an output, and, if you force it, the application that will receive it won't parse it correctly, so it doesn't make sense.